# Update Drupal from non-server computer

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, updates

I am working on my drupal site from the non server computer.  It is outdated and needs to be updated (from drupal 6 to 7). I am an admin on this site and i have all the credentials.  Can i update drupal 6 to 7 from a computer that does not have the drupal directory on it? (i.e from the drupal site on a laptop) Every time i click download on the recommended update it just downloads a .tar.gz file.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the non server computer' and what are 'all the credentials' that you have (mean from the Drupal site, from Server etc)? If you do not have access to the Drupal 6 site files and database you can do nothing. Because upgrade will upload new files. Drupal core cannot be upgrated/updated like modules. You must read firstly the UPGRADE.txt file inside Drupal root.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I meant all drupal credentials.  Im working on getting the server info. So in short the answer im getting from your reply is no this cannot be done from the drupal site. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can't upgrade Drupal core through UI. You can use Drush but this is a tool outside Drupal root.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade your drupal 6 live site by simply clicking on an `upgrade to D7` button.

Drupal is a modular system. If you upgrade the drupal core to version 7, all contributed and custom modules must be replaced by D7 counterparts. Even worse, Drupal 7 differs conceptionally from Drupal 6. An upgrade to D7 is possible, but not in an automatic process. You have to do the complex upgrade process by hand.

Your question suggests that you should probably stay with Drupal 6.